# TestContainers PostgreSQLContainer with Kotlin unit test: "Not enough information to infer type variable SELF"

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, testcontainers

I am trying to use `PostgreSQLContainer` from **TestContainers** (https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java + https://www.testcontainers.org/) in order to unit test my JPA repositories.

I declare my container like that:

```
private val postgresqlContainer = PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:12-alpine")
```

However, I encounter the following error, **from Intellij IDE**:

> Not enough information to infer type variable SELF

The full error when I try to launch the service is:

> Error:(26, 43) Kotlin: Type inference failed: Not enough information
> to infer parameter SELF in constructor PostgreSQLContainer<SELF :
> PostgreSQLContainer<SELF!>!>(p0: String!) Please specify it
> explicitly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TestContainers depends on construction of generic type `C<Self extends C<SELF>>`, but **Kotlin** don't like that.
My workaround was to define my own factory class:

```
class MyPostgreSQLContainer(imageName: String) : PostgreSQLContainer<MyPostgreSQLContainer>(imageName)
```

And I can use it like that:

```
private val postgresqlContainer = MyPostgreSQLContainer("postgres:12-alpine")
```

Answer (score 25):

This trick also works

```
private val postgresqlContainer = PostgreSQLContainer<Nothing>().apply {
    withDatabaseName("x")
    withUsername("y")
    withPassword("z")
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is now fixed on Kotlin side, see [this blog post](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew1530.html#improvements-to-type-inference-for-recursive-generic-types) for more details. Require a flag with Kotlin 1.5.30 and will be the default as of Kotlin 1.6.0.